# JSON : Fetch Particular row from an array using php

Tags: php, json, curl

Hi there I am trying to fetch a particular data from the JSON format that I have. 
I am using the prebuilt json for my practice.

The JSON Format is in this way :

```
[
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio 
 reprehenderit",
"body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et 
cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt   
rem eveniet architecto"
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "qui est esse",
"body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor 
beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil 
molestiae 
ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 3,
"title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
"body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut 
ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius 
odio et labore et velit aut"
}
]
```

and so on...

So what I have done is I fetched the title array from every Object.

Here is my Code :

```
<?php
$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" ;
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init() ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch) ;
curl_close($ch) ;

$data = json_decode($result);

foreach ($data as $datavalue) {
echo $datavalue->title;
echo "<br/>" ;
}
```

Now What I want is to show the title of a particular object, Say where user id =2 .

How can I persue that.
Please Help with my query. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: use `$data = json_decode($result, true);` to turn json string `$result` into an associative array you can itterate in your foreach loop.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. I already fetched the array values of name title.

I want to fetch the single title of particular userId @lovelace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition in your loop the check for your wanted row, when found, you can store it in a variable like this :

```
<?php


  $data = json_decode($result);

  $data = json_decode($result);

  $userId = 1;

  $result = null;

  foreach ($data as $datavalue) {
    echo $datavalue->title;
    if ($datavalue->userId == $userId) {
       $result = $datavalue;
       break;
    }
    echo "<br/>" ;
  }

var_dump($result); // if you want to display the title you can simply do $result->title but remember to check if $result is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
$id = 2;
getTitle($data, $id);

function getTitle($data = null, $id = null)
{
    foreach ($data as $datavalue) {
        if ($datavalue->id == $id) {
            echo $datavalue->title;
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the php `array_filter()` function.

```
//Your test data
$data = "[{\"userId\": 2,\"id\": 1,\"title\": \"sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit\",\"body\": \"quia et suscipitsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cumreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totamnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto\"},{\"userId\": 1,\"id\": 2,\"title\": \"qui est esse\",\"body\": \"est rerum tempore vitaesequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores nequefugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendisqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla\"},{\"userId\": 1,\"id\": 3,\"title\": \"ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut\",\"body\": \"et iusto sed quo iurevoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut advoluptatemdoloribus vel accusantium quis pariaturmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut\"}]";

//Decode the data to a PHP array rather than object
$data = json_decode( $data, true );

const searchKey  = "userId";
const searchTerm = 2;

//Filter that array
$data = array_filter( $data, function( $value ){
    //If the value in the searched key matches the value, return true
    if( $value[ searchKey ] === searchTerm ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

You'll see I am using two `const` vars, `searchKey` and `searchTerm`, you can change these to the values that you wish to search for in the PHP `array_filter()` function.

Here's some documentation on the php `array_filter()` function which you may find useful

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php